# Embedded Batch apex class

Tags: apex, batch

Hello Everyone i have This code-->

```
Date startDate = Date.today().toStartOfMonth();
Date endDate = startDate.addMonths(3).toStartOfMonth().addDays(-1);
List<IPfolio__Renewal__c> renewals = new List<IPfolio__Renewal__c>([SELECT Id FROM IPfolio__Renewal__c WHERE IPfolio__IP_Right__r.IPfolio__AppDate__c!=null and IPfolio__IP_Right__r.Split_Entity__c='BIIB' and IPfolio__IP_Right__r.Annuity_Responsible__c='YES' and  IPfolio__IP_Right__r.Annuity_Eligible__c ='YES' and IPfolio__IP_Right__r.IPfolio__IPR_Type__c in ('Patent','Design','Utility Model','Defensive Publication') and
IPfolio__Due_Date__c >=: startDate AND IPfolio__Due_Date__c <=:endDate]);
System.debug(renewals.size());
for(IPfolio__Renewal__c renewal : renewals){
    System.debug(renewal.Id);
    Database.executeBatch(new BatchQuotesRequest(startDate, renewal.Id));
}
```

I have embedded in Batch Apex Class Please help me.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I have to embedded this code in batch class

Comment: you are trying to call executeBatch method, do you want it to be done from batch class again?

Comment: I want this code done in batch apex class

Comment: What did you try so far?